# comparing variable to function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In this book:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code:current_user_p

The author does the following:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
```

my question is when there is a comparison, user == current_user; what is rails comparing? user == @current_user? or user.name == @current_user.name ?

What would hapen if I had the following

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    @other_user ||= User.find_by_other_token(cookies[:other_token])
  end
```

would ser == current_user compare other_user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `current_user` in `user == current_user` is a call to the `current_user` method, and in ruby a method returns the last statement that is executed. So in the example, `@current_user`  is being compared to `user`.

If you add `@other_user` to the `current_user` method, then you are correct in thinking that `user == current_user` would compare user to `@other_user`.

Answer (score 1):

`@current_user` → the instance variable
`current_user` → the method

So the `current_user?` method compares the return value of `current_user` (the method) to the `user` argument.

Here's the exact same code, but with slightly different names:

```
def get_current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def is_current_user?(user)
  user == get_current_user
end
```